# HTTP Post Encoding

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3.1, http-headers, http-post

**What I try to do**

---

Hello Guys,

I try to create a login for my server, that I can access the data on it over my app. For this i created a Methode called `'public void doLogin(final String username, final String password)'` . In this Methode I start a Thread in which I post the username and password to my server. Now to problem starts. When I do the post my server can't handle my post which looks like this: `'"username="+username+"&password="+password'`.

To try if its a serverside problem (infact its not) I made a post over `'curl -d'` with the same parameters and I get a response without any problems.

For your information the server runs on Ruby3

**Question**

---

How do I need to change my Post to the server that it can handle the data I send. By the way the string I post must look exactly like that: `'"username="+username+"&password="+password //this means username=LEUSER&password=LEPASS'`

Please tell me what I need to change, some code snippets or tutorials would be great. Down here you find the importrent codesnippets of the doLogin Methode

**Code**

---

```
public void doLogin(final String username, final String password) {

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                String URL = "http://192.168.110.126:3000/sessions.json"; //für momentane testzwecke

                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;

                try {
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("username="+username+"&password="+password);
                    post.setEntity(se);

                    response = client.execute(post);

                    if (response != null) {

                    //response handling
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("DataHandler", "URLConnection-Error" + e);
                }

            }

        };
        t.start();
    }
```

---

Please Guide me Regarding This.

Comment: pls go through this: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: If I had a rails app as a test server, I would test this using a `$.post()` in JavaScript and then inspect the POST (headers and entity) using Firebug or Chrome's debugging tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like you are sending a html form. In fact curl adds a content-type (with value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)  to the http header if you use the `-d` option.

So try to add the header field like this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
post.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to change is the String entity part. You should change with the following;

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();    
requestParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
requestParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
```

username & password are the variables that are input on the program.

Lastly, if you forget to set permission it also won't work. You need to set android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: like i said i get the response and the permission ist set.

Comment: maybe the main thread finishes before your doLogin function. you may need to join them.